# Passing variables between PHP forms.

Tags: php, variables, hidden-field

This is probably a really easy question but its early so yeah...

Basically I have a form:

```
<form name="varsForm" action="step2.php" id="formID" method="post">
```

And as I understand it within this for I created some hidden variables. as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="typeid" name="typeid" value="1" />
```

Because step2.php is set as an action, I though I was correct in assuming that the hidden variables would be passed to step2.php. However when I try to call them I am confronted with errors. I try and call them simply as follows:

```
<?php echo $_GET['typeid']; ?>
```

But it says that caseid is an undefined index, I assume I am not calling it correctly, anyone just put me right please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are submitting form via `POST` method, try `$_POST['typeid'];`

Alternatively change method to `GET`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using method="post" in form, you should use

```
<?php echo $_POST['typeid']; ?>
```

$_GET in PHP is used when you use HTTP GET method (method="get" in form tag).

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `$_GET` array while you're **posting** your infos.

You should use the `$_POST` array, or even the `$_REQUEST` array which handles both POST and GET.

Answer (score 1):

You have `method="post"` so the data is placed in the message body and not the query string. It will be accessible via `$_POST` not `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `method="post"` so look in $_POST :)

```
<?php echo $_POST['typeid']; ?>
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using HTTP `POST` method in your `<form>` you need to give the code as:

```
<?php echo $_POST['typeid']; ?>
```

Else, in the HTML change this:

```
<form method="get">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have method attribute in the form set to POST so values passed to step2.php will not be available in $_GET , it will be available in $_POST so to access the value you need to use $_POST['typeid'] .

And also Some times to avoid warnings OR notifications regarding index ( such as undefined index )  , you can first check for its existence and then process

Some what like this

```
if (array_key_exists('typeid', $_POST) )
{
     $typeid = $_POST['type_id'];
    // And do what ever you want to do with this value 
}
```